# Testing "trends over time" of dummy variables

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, stata, trend

Let us say this is an output of a model I ran in Stata, where `int_ret`is a continuous variable and `time1`-`time17` are time dummy variables. Reference is `time0`. I notice that the coefficients are significant at alpha=0.05 up til time 5 after which it stops being significant. I also notice that the coefficients for time decrease in magnitude from time1 to time5.

I am wondering if it is allowable for me to test if there was a "decreasing trend" between time1 and time 5 using the `test` command in Stata.

Example: `test time1=time2=time3=time4=time5=0`  or

```
  test time6=time7=time8=time9=time10=time11=time2=time13=0
```

I know that you have to enter all the dummy variables (except reference) in a model, but can you test the significance **just a subset** of the dummy variables (meaning, NOT all dummy variables) to determine "trend?"

Thanks

```
         |             Linearized
 int_ret |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
   time1 |   3.803034   1.569459     3.24   0.001     1.690201    8.557009
   time2 |   2.983938   1.145295     2.85   0.005     1.403566    6.343762
   time3 |   2.963121   1.412266     2.28   0.023      1.16145    7.559592
   time4 |   2.709894   1.137635     2.37   0.018     1.187634    6.183323
   time5 |   2.319515    1.00564     1.94   0.053     .9894511    5.437508
   time6 |   3.240125   2.107322     1.81   0.071     .9026434    11.63074
   time7 |   1.474064   .6102438     0.94   0.349     .6534528    3.325207
   time8 |   1.348993   .6327848     0.64   0.524     .5366498    3.391004
   time9 |   1.211208   .4933164     0.47   0.638     .5440385    2.696546
  time10 |   .7559254   .4048442    -0.52   0.602     .2638907    2.165379
  time11 |   2.224805   1.034081     1.72   0.086     .8925419    5.545686
  time12 |   1.676299   .6908775     1.25   0.211     .7457992    3.767742
  time13 |   1.233598   .6585384     0.39   0.694     .4321069    3.521729
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just include a time trend term in the model corresponding to the time dummies and segment the dataset to only include the five time steps you are concerned with? Applying a t-test to the coefficient on the trend term will tell you whether there is a statistically significant negative trend.

Comment: OK, I think I get what you are saying, so pls correct me if I am wrong...  First, generate a variable `TIMETREND` where `TIMETREND`=1 for `time0`, `TIMETREND`=2 for `time1`, ...,`TIMETREND`=14 for `time13` (`TIMETREND` goes from 1 to 14 b/c there are 14 time points)  then, `regress int_ret TIMETREND if (time>=0 &time<=5)`  The coefficient and sign on `TIMETREND` will tell me if there was significant decreasing trends b/w time 0 & time 5.  Did I read your response correctly? Thanks again